# Removing event listeners added by class

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I would like to understand how to remove the event listeners which are added by class as shown below (remove event for `div#mainMenu`)

[image]

I have tried all available methods but none to my avail. Also I dont see this issue in the extJS4.x version but only in 3.4 version. Any plain JS code to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have figured out how to resolve this issue. The way to remove the listener is to go to parent div component & call removeAllListeners() method on the element. The element can be accessed in the `afterRenderHandler` function using `this.el` & then calling `this.el.parent().removeAllListeners()` so that it removes the un-required listeners interfering with the user experience. You could call the parent method in a chained fashion if the listener identified is a nth level parent (call the method n times).

Ex: `this.el.parent().parent().removeAllListeners()`

You could also try to access the element directly if you have the ID by calling: `var el = Ext.get('mainMenu');` & then calling `el.removeAllListeners();`

Similar approach can be applied to any other JS frameworks by getting a handle to the element having an issue with the listeners.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***getEventListeners*** function to get listeners map of an element. After that use ***removeEventListener*** method, to remove event from element. You can use this function to remove all events from an element.

```
    function removeEventListeners(element, listenerMap) {
        Object.keys(listenerMap).forEach(function (name) {
            var listeners = listenerMap[name];
            listeners.forEach(function (object) {
                element.removeEventListener(name, object.listener);
            });
        });
    }
removeEventListeners(elementRef,getEventListeners(elementRef));
```

Comment: Isn't it specific to browser? Sorry I am unaware of JS world in depth. I actually tried but it errors out that method `getEventListeners` ain't available.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: getEventListeners is only support from chrome console.

Comment: It should be supported by all browsers!